# Is there a more efficient method than while loops for something that requires conditional checking?

Tags: r, loops

I have a problem that involves me wrapping a while loop around a bit of code that I believe can be vectorized efficiently. However, at each step, my stopping condition relies on the value at that stage. Consider this example as a representational model of my problem:
Generate N(0,1) random variables using `rnorm()`until you sample a value greater than an arbitrary value, `k`.

EDIT: A caveat of my problem, discussed in the comments, is that I cannot know, a priori, a good approximation of how many samples to take before my stopping condition.

One approach:

1. Using a while-loop, sample suitably sized normal random vectors (for instance, `rnorm(50)` to sample 50 standard normals at a time, or `rnorm(1)` if k is close to zero). Check this vector to see if any observations are greater than k.
2. If yes, stop and return all preceding values. Otherwise, combine your vector from step 1 with a new vector you make by repeating step 1.

Another approach would be to specify a completely overkill number of random draws for that given k. This might mean if k=2, sample 1,000 normal random variables using `rnorm(1000)`.

Leveraging the vectorization that R offers in the second case gives faster results than the loop version in cases where the overkill number is not too much larger than necessary, but in my problem, I don't have a good intuition for how many runs I need to do, so I'd need to be conservative.

The question follows: Is there a way to do a highly-vectorized procedure, like method 2, but using conditional checking like method 1? Is doing small vectorized operations like `rnorm(50)` the "fastest" way, when considering that the highly-vectorized method is element-per-element faster, but more wasteful?

Comment: I'm not sure how well anyone will be able to answer this, since vectorizing R code generally requires fairly detailed knowledge of the entire block of code you're trying to improve.

Comment: The code itself is vectorized, but my stopping condition involves checking each element, so I'm losing a lot of the benefit of having the code fully-vectorized. I was hoping of a slick R trick that gives the speed of the `apply` suite, but allows me to stop once I've hit my condition.

Comment: Use your third approach. You don't need an "overkill" number of draws.  You know the distribution and the value you want to be greater than, so you know the probability of sampling that number.  E.g. if `k=3` then you should get ~3 numbers greater than `k` if you run `rnorm(1e3)`.  `which(rnorm(1e3))` tells you the first element that matches.

Comment: I'm implementing a stochastic optimization procedure for which I'm unsure of the probability of occurrences until my stopping criterion.

Comment: That would be useful to mention in your question.

Comment: Maybe a good compromise, half way between your two methods, would be to increase the number of new samples between each loop iteration. For example, instead of taking 50 at a time, do 50, 100, 200, 400, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of my earlier suggestion: use your first approach but increase the number of new samples between each iteration, e.g., instead of `50` new samples at each iteration, multiply that number by two between each iteration: `50`, then `100`, `200`, `400`, etc.

With your sample size following a divergent geometric series, you are guaranteed to exit in a "few" iterations.

```
sample.until.thresh <- function(FUN, exit.thresh,
                                sample.start = 50,
                                sample.growth = 2) {

   sample.size    <- sample.start
   all.values     <- list()
   num.iterations <- 0L

   repeat {
      num.iterations <- num.iterations + 1L
      sample.values  <- FUN(sample.size)
      all.values[[num.iterations]] <- sample.values

      above.thresh <- sample.values > exit.thresh
      if (any(above.thresh)) {
         first.above <- match(TRUE, above.thresh)
         all.values[[num.iterations]] <- sample.values[1:first.above]
         break
      }

      sample.size <- sample.size * sample.growth
   }

   all.values <- unlist(all.values)

   return(list(num.iterations = num.iterations,
               sample.size    = length(all.values),
               sample.values  = all.values))
}

set.seed(123456L)
res <- sample.until.thresh(rnorm, 5)
res$num.iterations
# [1] 16
res$sample.size
# [1] 2747703
```

Comment: This is actually a really nice approach. Incrementally increasing the amount I vectorize by works pretty well when I don't know how many samples I need. Thanks!